# Discord.py : How do I get user input?

Tags: python, discord.py

I started coding a command for my discord bot which lets users interact with it. I've got almost everything right (thanks to Stack Overflow), except getting user input. The "input" command doesn't seem to work.

```
@client.command()
async def bot (ctx):
   async def Bot1(ctx):
    while True:
      Initiate = input ("Type in anything to start, type 'Quit' to end ")
      if Initiate == 'Hello':
        await ctx.send ("Hello there!")
      elif Initiate == 'Quit':
        break
        
      else:
        Responses = ['How are you doing today', 'What do you want to talk about', 'The bot is at your service']
        Response = random.choose(Responses)
        await ctx.send (Response)

   await ctx.send (await Bot1(ctx))
```

Comment: `input` will ask for an input on the command terminal. If you want to read a user's input via discord chat, you must use the `on_message` method

Comment: If you use the current method you won't have `ctx`. You can get `ctx` when you get the message from a discord server or you can define it manually

Answer (score 0):

You are using input(), you are trying to get input from the user in the terminal, use on_message or something like this:

```
msg = await client.wait_for("message", check=check, timeout=60)
```

or if you still can't get the input, use this [website](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/discord.py+get+user+input)